# Android - How to create facebook style notification dialog

Tags: android

How to create facebook style notification dialog as following in android

[image]

Comment: Ask Google. Or post your code to have help from SO

Answer (score 2):

it's not a `Dialog` it is `Pop up Window` u can take a look at this tutorial

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html